# Problem for adding padding and text-aling in a Grid Column with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

First, sorry for my English.

I have a problem, I'm working on web page for a course, and I need to use css class for add padding and `text-align`, but my class don't work and I don't know I would to do.

html code:

```
<section id="features">
  <div class="row">
    <div class"features-box col-lg-4">
      <i class="features-icon fas fa-check-circle fa-4x"></i>
      <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
      <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
    </div>
    <div class"features-box col-lg-4">
      <i class="features-icon fas fa-bullseye fa-4x"></i>
      <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
      <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
    </div>
    <div class"features-box col-lg-4">
      <i class="features-icon fas fa-heart fa-4x"></i>
      <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
      <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
Css code:

#features {
 padding: 7% 15%;
}

.features-box {
 background-color: red;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5%;
}

.features-icon {
 color: #ef8172;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
 }

.features-icon:hover {
 color: #ff4c68;
 }
```

My `.features-box` class don't work, but my all other classes work normally. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't put the = sign after class:

```
<div class="features-box col-lg-4">
```

but you write:

```
<div class"features-box col-lg-4">
```

Comment: I didn’t notice!

Comment: Thanks, the wrong is this, I've spend a hour of my time to find this and I can't found this.. this is really embarrasing. Thanks so much, I'm student and I'm learn now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.col-lg-4.features-box {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}
```

Bootstrap 4 may override your own styles, if you use a custom class without `!important` for each rule alongside a default one. Please, consider also that Bootstrap adds a space between columns you can manage via SCSS too.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll consider this next time, I'm a student now and all of tips is important for me, thanks so much.